# Resert IBM system x3650 fault led

Tags: power-supply-unit, ibm-xseries, diagnostic

I got OVERSPEC, PS1 and PS2 fault led on my x3650. I tried to replace one PS but nothing changes. The power supplyp seems to work properly and it is very strange to broke both PS at the same time.
I tried to reset the system log, reboot, but these leds are still on.
What can i do?

Comment: Have you contacted IBM support?  Reset the light path diags?  Reset the IMM?

Comment: IBM told me to contact my local IBM partner, my local partner told me to reset the bios and system log...

Comment: see if this helps: http://content.etilize.com/user-manual/1023236389.pdf - normally on the xSeries a reset of the LPD itself, followed by a full shutdown (remove power cords after for 1 minute), is enough.  Sometimes though, I've had to reset the IMM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need update - Baseboard Management Controller (BMC) Version 1.44 build ID GFBT60AUS

System machine types 7978 and 1913.
Please read - https://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/XSA/010ds/0/ibm_fw_bmc_gfbt60a_dos_noarch.txt

Baseboard Management Controller Version 1.44 (Build ID GFBT60AUS) - Suggested Fixes:

- Fixed the erroneous Power Supply(PS) 2 fault and recovery messages
- Fixed the problem that sometimes PS LED still on after power re-applied